# Change one link into two on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to create a link that changes into two links when you hover over the text. You can see something like what I want to do here: https://www.kenzo.com/en/ You can see that the `collections` link changes into two separate links for men and women when you hover over the link. At the moment I have managed to create a link that separates into two words when hovered over but not into two links.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li><a href="#" id="nav-item1"><span>Collection</span></a></li>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
#nav-item1:hover span {
    display:none;
}

#nav-item1:hover:before {
    content: "Men Women";
}
```

So the text changes which is great, but I haven't quite figured out how to turn the text into two separate links. I'm not sure if I have to use JS for this or not, as my JS knowledge terrible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right you can try something like this:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  display: none;
  margin-left: .3em;
}

li:hover span {
  display: none;
}

li:hover a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <span>Collection</span>
  <a href="#" id="nav-item1">Man</a>
  <a href="#" id="nav-item2">Women</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I changed the nav items to have a common class of `nav-item`, and then changed the `a` in your code to `.nav-item`. Worked a treat thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here is a small breakdown of how you can achieve this.
There is a block element on the top of things.

Then there are two hidden elements that are children of the block element.

And when you hover over the block element the other ones are shown.

You can also hide the child element that contains the text on hover.

```css
.block:hover .hide {
  display: inline;
}

.block {
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="default text">Hover</span>
  <a class="hide" href="#">Snowball</a>
  <a class="hide" href="#">Kitten</a>
<div>
```

Comment: In this example, I would also want to hide the "Hover" text when you hover over it, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.splitted {
 display: none;
}

.links:hover .one-link {
 display: none;
}

.links:hover .splitted {
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span class="links">
  <a href="#" class="one-link">Collection</a>
  <a href="#" class="splitted">Men</a>
  <a href="#" class="splitted">Women</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```css
#nav-item1{
  position: relative;
}

#nav-item1:before,
#nav-item1:after{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  color: #000;
}

#nav-item1:hover:before,
#nav-item1:hover:after{
  display: block;
}

#nav-item1:before{
  content: 'Men';
  right: 50%;
}

#nav-item1:after{
  content: 'Women';
  left: 50%;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="nav-item1"><span>Collection</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```